# Can smaller result set ever gives a slower execution time as compare to larger result set？

Tags: sql-server

```
--Case 1 
SET @name = 'ABC';

-- Case 2
SET @name = null;

SELECT * 
FROM someTable 
WHERE (@name IS NULL OR name = @name)
```

From my understanding, when the result set is huge, the execution time tends to be slower, which in other word Case 2 should always be slower than Case 1.

We needed to have performance test on the query and hence I'm wondering can I safely assume that if the result set is large and the execution time is acceptable, I don't have to worry of any other input value that yields smaller result set.

Is there by any chance whereby given the same query, the smaller result set is executed slower than the larger result set?

Comment: is this just hypothetical or do you have a real world issues? If it's a real problem, provide more details.

Comment: This is just a hypothetical question. We needed to performance test on the query and hence I'm wondering can I safely assume that if the result set is large and the execution time is acceptable, I don't have to worry of any other input value that yields smaller result set

Comment: I think both will have similar performance unless you have a index on `name` column. If you don't have index in both the scenario the full table scan will be done